# Hide extension for action class in struts2.0.14 version

Tags: struts2, struts, action

I need to hide action extension in Struts2.0.14 version.

By configuring the below things it is working fine in Struts2.1.8 version. But it not working in the 2.0.14 version, i am getting these sort of errors(i mentioned the errors below)

In the `web.xml` i updated the filter code as

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then in the struts.xml i updated like this

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/>
```

Result of updating like this is:

> I can access the action file as
>   http://ip.com:8080/project/actionName.  But javascript, css and
>   image files are not loading.  So i tried to use
>   struts.action.excludePattern, but it is not available for 2.0.14
>   version

Then in the struts.xml i updated like this

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/>
```

Result of updating like this is:

> I can access the action file as
>   http://ip.com:8080/project/actionName.  If not giving the dot in
>   the end, it is not working.  Same result is coming when giving the
>   value=",,action" or value=",action"

Can anyone tell me, whether we can remove the extension in struts2.0.14 version.

Comment: So what do you want a dot at the end?

Comment: No i dont want dot, but as per that codes result, it is accessing if i am ending dot, so i need to ignore the dot

Comment: The `struts.action.extension` with `value=","` should work.

Comment: Why there is dot in action name?

Comment: I used Struts 2.0.14 up to six months ago, then the company opened its standards to 2.3. It turned out that it takes up to 30 minutes to migrate an 1-month application, and 4 hours to migrate an 1.5 year application, that makes use of struts-dojo and xml validation too (and concurrently i migrated Spring 2.0 to Spring 3.1). It would be probably faster than even resolve this issue, just think about it, and eventually go "whine" to your pm ;)

Comment: @Anto if you could move to at least 2.1.9 then you could try regex to exclude dot from mapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
<struts>

  <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/> 

  <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="SayStruts2">
        <result>pages/printStruts2.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>

</struts>
```

[see Here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-remove-the-action-suffix-extension-in-struts-2/)

Comment: For me also it is working for Struts 2.1.8 version, but for this 2.0.14 version it is not working

Comment: Use a "," for no extension.

Comment: you can also use `<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",json"/>` if you're also using the json plugin